# Detecting time range in ios using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nscalendar

Lets say I have some rules for displaying a message like below

between 00:00-12:00 -> morning

between 12:01-14:00 -> noon

between 14:01-17:00 -> afternoon

between 17:00-23:59 -> evening

if current mobile time is between 00:00 and 12:00 I should get morning 
How can I do that please guide.

Answer (score 4):

This should do the job

```
func check(time: NSDate) -> String? {
    let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
    formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "GMT")
    guard let
        beginNoon = formatter.dateFromString("12:00"),
        beginAfternoon = formatter.dateFromString("14:00"),
        beginEvening = formatter.dateFromString("17:00")
        else { return nil }

    if time.compare(beginNoon) == .OrderedAscending { return "Morning" }
    if time.compare(beginAfternoon) == .OrderedAscending { return "Noon"}
    if time.compare(beginEvening) == .OrderedAscending { return "Afternoon" }
    return "Evening"
}
```

### Test

```
check(formatter.dateFromString("10:00")!) // "Morning"
check(formatter.dateFromString("13:00")!) // "Noon"
check(formatter.dateFromString("15:00")!) // "Afternoon"
check(formatter.dateFromString("22:00")!) // "Evening"
```

### Considerations

Your ranges are inconsistent

Here you are including the `left` and `right` boundaries

```
00:00-12:00 -> morning
```

here you are including only the `right` boundary

```
12:01-14:00 -> noon
14:01-17:00 -> afternoon
```

and here only the `left` boundary :)

```
between 17:00-23:59
```

In my code, the `left` boundary in only included while the `right` one is excluded.